# JMeter javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake Load testing

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to test my API using Jmeter Load testing and i am encountering this error whenever i tried to test 10 or more concurrent request in 20 seconds or more:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.hc.LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory.java:92)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$JMeterDefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HTTPHC4Impl.java:326)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:850)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:561)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:67)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1282)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1271)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:627)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:551)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:490)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    ... 27 more
```

10 concurrent user for 10 seconds is successful but when i up my testing, some request replied the above error and some request had been successful during the testing. I think this is not a code issue anymore. In this regard, May i know what is the problem for this? I am trying to test my API **from my workstation(Windows) to Linux Dev server where the API is located** and i am curious why only some request replied with this error while some is successful since my API URL uses HTTPS.

Comment: Just to update, i loaded my ssl certificate (.pfx) in the keystore and JMeter still responds the error

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting this `SSL peer shut down incorrectly` error only under the load most probably it means that your system under test gets overloaded and cannot properly respond/gracefully end the connection.

- Check your system under test logs for any suspicious entries
- Make sure that the system under test has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, Network, etc, it can be done using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)

From JMeter side of things you can:

- Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
- The same as for the system under test - make sure that JMeter doesn't lack underlying operating system resources, if it does - consider [running JMeter in distributed mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
- You can also add [`javax.net.debug=all`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) line to *system.properties* file, this way you will get way more information regarding underlying connections problems in stdout
- In addition you can add the next lines to *log4j2.xml* file, this way you will see more details on network connections level in the [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

  ```
  <Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
  <Logger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="debug"/>
  ```

Comment: Hi Sir, upon checking in the server, the cpu usage during testing were only 32% maximum and ram usage was between 200-300mb with 8gb limit. May i know if this were still server problem if the usage were low?